# While using flask in python, I am not able to get the 'extend' feature to work properly

Tags: python, html, flask, frontend, web-frontend

I'm new to programming. I decided to try to create a web app using flask, python, and HTML. I set up three files; two HTML and one python:

This is the HTML file that should have information replaced (`didntwork.html`):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h3>Information:</h3>
      {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
                                        .
```

This is the file that should input information to the first (`connection.html`):

```
{% extends 'didntwork.html' %}
{% block body %}
<h4>information content</h4>
{% endblock %}
                                        .
```

Finally, this is the logic for the flask app in python (`main.py`):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('didntwork.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Unfortunately, the `extends` in the second HTML file does not seem to be recognized, and the information in its block will not be replaced in the first HTML file (`didntwork.html`).

This is the output:

[image: This is the output.]

The expected outcome should append an h4 tag to the body with the phrase 'information content'.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `{% extends 'didntwork.html' %}`. From what I can tell the file that contains this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <h3>Information:</h3>
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

is your **`connection.html`** file.

You are extending to the same file you're rendering (`didntwork.html`). You have to change the `extends` line to extend your base html, **`connection.html`** in this case.

Use this code in your `didntwork.html`:

```
{% extends 'connection.html' %}
{% block body %}
<h4>information content</h4>
{% endblock %}
```

You can find more information in [Template Inheritance](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/)

**UPDATE BASE ON CLARIFICATION**

You're rendering the wrong file in your `route`.
You should render the `connection.html` and this will extends your `didntwork.html` file.

Comment: Sorry, the files were not named in my original post, which may have been misleading; I've edited it with the appropriate file names.

Comment: Sorry, you accidentally mixed up the file names. Thanks for your response but adding your provided code results in a ```RecursionError```.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your clarification. Try that and let me know

Comment: I tried updating the route in ```main.py``` to ```return render_template('connection.html')```, however the element is stilil not appended and just shows 'Informations:' like before. Shall i post an imgur link of ```main.py```.looks like now?

Comment: Thank you! Restarting the server worked. I have marked your answer as correct.